# getting chrome tabs in the correct order

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I am trying to get a list of chrome tabs in the same order as they are listed in the tab bar of the browser.

This is my code:

```
var automationElements = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);

// Find `New Tab` element
var propCondNewTab = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "New Tab");
var elemNewTab = automationElements.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, propCondNewTab);

// Get parent of `New Tab` element
var treeWalker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
var elemTabStrip = treeWalker.GetParent(elemNewTab);

// Loop through all tabs
var tabItemCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.TabItem);
foreach (AutomationElement tabItem in elemTabStrip.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, tabItemCondition)) {
    var nameProperty = tabItem.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.NameProperty);
    Debug.WriteLine("title: " + nameProperty.ToString());
}
```

However in the foreach loop the titles are not in the same order as they are in the browser. Is there a way to get them in the correct order?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a direct way to get the order of the tabs. What you can do, is get the position of the rectangle of the tab, and order your tabs by their rectangle's position on the X-axis.

A very quick example, where I use a `SortedDictionary` to save the tabs and their X-values. Afterwards, a loop runs through the keys in the dictionary and extracts the tab items. Because the dictionary is sorted, the keys are in order, so the list will be in the order the tabs are shown in the browser.

```
SortedDictionary<double, AutomationElement> orderedTabItems = new SortedDictionary<double, AutomationElement>();

// Loop through all tabs
var tabItemCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.TabItem);
foreach (AutomationElement tabItem in elemTabStrip.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, tabItemCondition))
{
    Rect rectangleProperty = (Rect)tabItem.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.BoundingRectangleProperty);
    orderedTabItems.Add(rectangleProperty.X, tabItem);
}

for(int i = 0; i < orderedTabItems.Keys.Count; i++)
{
    var key = orderedTabItems.Keys.ElementAt(i);
    var tabItem = orderedTabItems[key];
    var nameProperty = tabItem.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.NameProperty);
    Debug.WriteLine("index: " + i + ", title: " + nameProperty.ToString());
}
```

I'm sure a better solution is possible. This was my first attempt at using `System.Windows.Automation`.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, to access the `X` property of the rectangle, you need to add a reference to `WindowsBase.dll` and reference this in the code:

```
using System.Windows;
```

Comment: That's good, but like I wrote, it is my first try at using `System.Windows.Automation`, so there is probably a much neater way to do it. Honestly, by using the approach that @stamhaney suggests, it "feels right", to get the tabs from a `page tab list`, instead of investigating UI rectangle positions :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the correct order of the tabs using Microsoft Active Accessibility (MSAA). This method does not rely on screen coordinates like the other answer. Here is what you need to do:

1. Get the Top Window Accessible Object of Chrome for the class `Chrome_WidgetWin_1` and title "`New Tab - Google Chrome`"
2. Get the Accessible object for the role "`page tab list`"
3. Get the Accessible Children for the object found in point 2
4. Iterate through the list of children and display the accName property.

There is a good [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38906/UI-Automation-Using-Microsoft-Active-Accessibility) which can help you get started with using MSAA

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit? I'm already stuck on your first point :D

Comment: @gartenriese , Added some more info and a link on MSAA

Comment: In your link they get the top window accessible objects in a list by calling `GetTopWindowAccessibleList`, however that function is never explained. How can I get these accessible objects?